# docker-py: Login to private registry using ~/.docker/config.json auth token

Tags: python, docker, docker-registry, dockerpy

I stored my credentials to access a private registry in the `~/.docker/config.json` file. Therefore I can simply run `docker login <url>` without explicitely stating my credentials. Is there a way to replicate this behaviour using [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)?

All I could find was this [login](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.daemon.DaemonApiMixin.login) method, which always requires a username. Using the cli all I need is the registry host name (and the `~/.docker/config.json` file with the auth token to this registry).

Is that somehow achievable? T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the `login` method and options available.

```
login()
Authenticate with a registry. Similar to the docker login command.

Parameters: 
    username (str) – The registry username
    password (str) – The plaintext password
    email (str) – The email for the registry account
    registry (str) – URL to the registry. E.g. https://index.docker.io/v1/
    reauth (bool) – Whether or not to refresh existing authentication on the Docker server.
   dockercfg_path (str) – Use a custom path for the Docker config file (default $HOME/.docker/config.json if present, otherwise``$HOME/.dockercfg``)
```

And as per that, ***dockercfg_path***, is present for the login method where you can use that file.

From experimenting, Though, that this `username` is ignored for the credentials saved in .docker/config.json, so I just use a random value and it is working.

Comment: But as far as I understand `username` is a required parameter. Which I don't want to provide since I want to use the one inside the `config.json` file.

Comment: Can you please try and implement with config

Comment: `login(username, password=None, email=None, registry=None, reauth=False, dockercfg_path=None)`, from the function signature you can see that `username` is always required. From experimenting with it I noticed though, that this username is ignored for the credentials saved in `.docker/config.json`, so I just use a random value and it is working.

Comment: That's great then.

Comment: Can you add the information from my comment to your answer? Then I gladly accept it :) Just want to save the next person reading this question from reading through comments.

Comment: Please have a look